# How to redirect a user after authorization with respect to a role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

        if (User.IsInRole("User")) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin"); 
        }

        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
        { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator"); 
        }
    }
}
```

I want a user, such as an administrator, to be redirected to his page immediately after logging in, and a user to his page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            var user =  await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                if (roles.Contains("User")) { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
                if (roles.Contains("Admin")) { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin"); }
                if (roles.Contains("Administrator")) { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator"); }
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }
```